# Reactive Function is not working

Tags: r, highcharts, shinydashboard

I am trying to get radio button values in server.R and after getting the value,want to perform some filter on the basis of selected value of radio button. 
Code is as follow:

### ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(highcharter)

shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                dashboardHeader(title = img(src='BoA.png',height= 60,align = 
'middle')),
                dashboardSidebar(
                sidebarMenu(
                id ="tabs",
                menuItem("Block Trade",icon = icon("bank"),tabName = "blocktrade")
              )
            ),
            dashboardBody(
              tabItems(
                tabItem(
                  "blocktrade",tabBox(
                    id="tabset1",height = "475px",width = "1050px",
                    tabPanel("VOLUME BY CLIENT/STATUS",
                             column(width = 12,
                                    fluidRow(          
                                      box(width = 8,highchartOutput("block_trade_hcontainer1",height = "400px",width = "400px")),
                                      box(width = 4,title = "Status",radioButtons("status",label = NULL ,choices = c("Amended"="Amended","New"="New"),selected = "Amended",inline = TRUE))
                                    )
                             )
                    )

                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
 )
```

### server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(xlsx)

block_trade<-read.xlsx('Blocktrade.xlsx',1)

shinyServer(function(input,output){
  nStatus<-reactive({input$status})
  block_trade<-block_trade[block_trade$Status == nStatus(),]
  block_trade_volume_by_client<-data.frame(table(block_trade$Associated.Client))

  output$block_trade_hcontainer1<-renderHighchart({
  highchart()%>%
  hc_chart(type="column")%>%
  hc_xAxis(categories=block_trade_volume_by_client$Var1)%>%
  hc_add_series(name="Quantity",data=block_trade_volume_by_client$Freq)%>%
  hc_exporting(enabled=TRUE)
  })
})
```

So,at server side i am unable to get radiobutton value to filter block trade data.

Comment: Please add code here (not just link)

Comment: And please try to make a small reproducible example. Without seeing the whole server function, it is almost impossible to spot the error.

Comment: is it good now? @AntonBelousov

Comment: fine for you? @SeGa

Comment: Lookgs better yes. Although a small snippet of the xls-file, as data frame for exmaple would also be nice, otherwise the code is not executable on its own.  But from a first impression `block_trade` and `block_trade_volume_by_client` should be in some observe or reactive function too.. not just in the server file

Comment: @SeGa Sorry but could not share data because of some policies :(

Comment: @Gaurav Chaudhari, I understand that and I wasnt asking for the real dataset, just some fake data, that is structured in the same way as the original datset. Then your example code is executable on its own and can be reproduced by others and solved faster ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted your reactive function a bit, as it was only listening for the input$status, which is already a "reactive" value. So I moved `block_trade` and `block_trade_volume_by_client` in the reactive. So, whenever you change the `input$status`, the data is filtered accordingly.
And in the renderHighchart function you call the filtered data with `nStatus <- block_trade_volume_by_client()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(highcharter)
library(xlsx)


ui <- {shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                dashboardHeader(title = img(src='BoA.png',height= 60,align = 
                                              'middle')),
                dashboardSidebar(
                  sidebarMenu(
                    id ="tabs",
                    menuItem("Block Trade",icon = icon("bank"),tabName = "blocktrade")
                  )
                ),
                dashboardBody(
                  tabItems(
                    tabItem(
                      "blocktrade",tabBox(
                        id="tabset1",height = "475px",width = "1050px",
                        tabPanel("VOLUME BY CLIENT/STATUS",
                                 column(width = 12,
                                        fluidRow(          
                                          box(width = 8,highchartOutput("block_trade_hcontainer1",height = "400px",width = "400px")),
                                          box(width = 4,title = "Status",radioButtons("status",label = NULL ,choices = c("Amended"="Amended","New"="New"),selected = "Amended",inline = TRUE))
                                        )
                                 )
                        )

                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
  )
)}


block_trade<-read.xlsx('Blocktrade.xlsx',1)


server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
  nStatus<-reactive({
    req(input$status)
    block_trade<-block_trade[block_trade$Status == input$status,]
    block_trade_volume_by_client<-data.frame(table(block_trade$Associated.Client))
    block_trade_volume_by_client
    })

  output$block_trade_hcontainer1<-renderHighchart({
    req(input$status)
    block_trade_volume_by_client <- nStatus()

    highchart()%>%
      hc_chart(type="column")%>%
      hc_xAxis(categories=block_trade_volume_by_client$Var1)%>%
      hc_add_series(name="Quantity",data=block_trade_volume_by_client$Freq)%>%
      hc_exporting(enabled=TRUE)
  })
})
```

Comment: Working fine. Thanks and Kudos to you @SeGa